# JSF keep text value in inputtext

Tags: jsf

I have a plain inputtext field. when I enter a value and submit the input field is cleared. anyway the text entered in the field can be kept when submitted? Difficult to explain but I don't mean storing the value in a bean, I mean keeping the text itself in the field.

code of my input:

```
<h:inputText id="description" 
             value="#{timeLoggingDetailController.selected.description}" 
             title="#{bundle.CreateTimeLoggingDetailTitle_description}" 
             size="18" />
```

When I fill in the field:

[image: Filled]
After I submit:

[image: Cleared]
I want to keep the text in the field after submit:

[image: Submit]

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to keep the value in the inputText or not ?

Comment: I am storing the value yes, let me change my question, In my field on my page I type the word "TEST", when I submit the field is cleared, I want the word "TEST" to remain in the field so that when I submit again it will submit the word "TEST" again.

Comment: IIRC, the next displayed value does come back from the bean...  You'd have to either override it with some ECMAscript on the display side, or use a bean with larger scope (session?) to keep the value.

Comment: Please edit and post the problem in SSCCE flavor. The cause of the problem is not visible in information provided so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't preserve the `inputText` value after submitting the form without using a bean (`@SessionScoped`, for example), because every time you hit a link or a button, the JSF component tree is (re)created/restored and each component in the component tree [extracts its new value from the request parameters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_life_cycle.htm).

Therefore, if you want to have the value you've entered before submitting the form, you will need to store it as a value of a property in the managed bean.

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks. Will get it sorted

Comment: This answer isn't making any sense and containing falsehoods. JSF preserves inputs already by default, even with request scoped beans or even without any bean. OP's concrete problem is caused elsewhere. Perhaps OP incorrectly reinitialized `selected` property, or sent a redirect after submit. That this answer is upvoted twice is actually  very sad as it indicates the stupidity of the average JSF user. Please please test your own answer on a true runtime environment before you post it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
@ViewScoped
```

It would keep the data